# Modeling nestedness in terms of repeated measures AND site in lme4 in R?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I have $30$ students from $4$ schools (named: `W, X, Y, Z`). Two of the schools (`X and Y`) have received a Treatment (`T`), and two other schools (`W and Z`) served as control (`C`).

I have tested all students $3$ different times (`time`) and also know their gender (`gender`) as a covariate.

Using `lme4` or another appropriate `R` package, I wonder how to measure the effect of the `group` (`C` or `T`) in this design given nestedness of students (`st.id`) within `time` and within schools (`sc.id`)?

I highly appreciate an `R` demonstration using data below.

```
set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(st.id = rep(1:10,each = 3), sc.id = c(rep("W",6), rep("X",9), rep("Y",6), rep("Z",9)), 
              time = rep(1:3,10), group = c(rep("C", 6), rep("T",15), rep("C",9)), 
              gender = sample(c("M", "F"), 30, replace = T), y = round(rnorm(30,960,150)))
```

Here is the model I'm using right now:

```
lme4::lmer(y ~ group * gender * time + (time|sc.id/st.id), data = dat)
```